# Enable in-app payments in Chrome Webstore

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, chrome-web-store

I want to enable charging for apps for my Chrome Webstore developer account but can't figure out how to do that. Webstore docs say you can accept payments from EU but when I try to register a Checkout merchant account (using this link: http://checkout.google.com/sell) I only have the US and the UK.
The appropriate link in Webstore dashboard (to enable payments) leads to Wallet promotional page which simple sends you to your Wallet account. Help articles doesn't help either.
I'd appreciate an advice from European developers on how to enable payments in Webstore.